# Custom App start Screen

Tags: javascript, css, html, cordova, mobile

I am trying to create a mobile app with `HTML5`, `CSS`, and `JavaScript` and want to use `Phonegap` Build for compiling it for the mobile devices.

So most mobile apps in an App Store have custom start Screen when you start the app it shows you at the beginning the Company logo or game logo. So how is it possible to do it with HTML5, CSS, and JavaScript.

I already searching use the search engines with may keyword combine with Phonegap or Titanium to get an example or an idea how to do that.
But nothing, so many maybe you could give me any advice.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for the splashscreen is in the link below. Not used phonegap build but I assume you configure it in the same way.

It is done by an image rather than html & css.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/config_ref_images.md.html